# Apache kafka exactly once implementation not sending messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, idempotent

I am trying to implement exactly-once semantic with idempotent Producer & transaction for one of the banks usecase.

I have created producer like this:

```
String topicName = "exonce";

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 1);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

props.put("enable.idempotence", "true");
props.put("transactional.id", "1");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("transaction.timeout.ms","160000");

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer
   <String, String>(props);
producer.initTransactions();
producer.beginTransaction();

producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName,           "val_"));

producer.commitTransaction();
System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
producer.close();
```

But I am not able to get anything in consumer side & also i dont see the sysout: "Message sent successfully" at-least sysout should have come/shown.

**Program isnt ending it waits for something to happen (no errors/exception).  waiting at: producer.initTransactions(); line**

This is the log:

> 17/07/12 08:46:36 INFO producer.ProducerConfig: ProducerConfig values: 
>     acks = all
>
> batch.size = 16384
>
> bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
>
> buffer.memory = 33554432
>
> client.id =
>
> compression.type = none
>
> connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
>
> enable.idempotence = true
>
> interceptor.classes = null
>
> key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
>
> linger.ms = 1
>
> max.block.ms = 60000
>
> max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
>
> max.request.size = 1048576
>
> metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
>
> metric.reporters = []
>
> metrics.num.samples = 2
>
> metrics.recording.level = INFO
>
> metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
>
> partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
>
> receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
>
> reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
>
> reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
>
> request.timeout.ms = 30000
>
> retries = 1
>
> retry.backoff.ms = 100
>
> transaction.timeout.ms = 160000
>
> transactional.id = 1
>
> value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
>
> 17/07/12 08:46:36 INFO producer.KafkaProducer: Instantiated a transactional producer.
>
> 17/07/12 08:46:36 INFO producer.KafkaProducer: Overriding the default max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 1 since idempontence is enabled.
>
> 17/07/12 08:46:37 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.11.0.0
>
> 17/07/12 08:46:37 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : cb8625948210849f
>
> 17/07/12 08:46:37 INFO internals.TransactionManager: [TransactionalId 1] ProducerId set to -1 with epoch -1

I am not sure what mistake I am making here.

*I am using kafka-0.11.0.0*

please let me know if you need anymore information.

Appreciate your help & support.

Thanks

Raj

Answer (score 4):

This is what I found out after following the hint that transactions by default require 3 brokers. Furthermore, by default, transactions require 2 replicas in sync.

In my Docker based environment I thus reduced those two settings on my broker:

```
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
```

These settings correspond to the documented settings from https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation.html#brokerconfigs

```
transaction.state.log.min.isr
transaction.state.log.replication.factor
```

Note: ISR stands for in-sync replicas

And one more: In case you are using confluent's default platform setup (not the docker containers), these settings are preconfigured already.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a single node installation? Can you check your server.log for whether the `__transaction_state` topic was created properly? It needs 3 replicas in order to be created, and it is only created on the first `initTransactions` request. So if you don't have enough brokers, the creation of the topic will fail, and the `initTransactions` request may block forever.

Comment: `transaction.state.log.replication.factor` is 3 by default, need to decrease this value in devlopment to 2 because it is the minimum that kafka acecpts in transacional mode

Answer (score -1):

Updated answer to try running the example in the javadoc as a test that the broker is configured correctly for 0.11 with 0.11 client protocol

```
 Properties props = new Properties();


props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
 props.put("transactional.id", "my-transactional-id");
 Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());

 producer.initTransactions();

 try {
     producer.beginTransaction();
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("my-topic", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));
     producer.commitTransaction();
 } catch (ProducerFencedException | OutOfOrderSequenceException | AuthorizationException e) {
     // We can't recover from these exceptions, so our only option is to close the producer and exit.
     producer.close();
 } catch (KafkaException e) {
     // For all other exceptions, just abort the transaction and try again.
     producer.abortTransaction();
 }
 producer.close();
```

Comment: I don't think so, javadoc: public void close()
"Close this producer. This method blocks until all previously sent requests complete"

Comment: Thanks for the response @hans-jespersen & @michal-borowiecki , as I told in original question the execution isn't crossing **producer.initTransactions()** invocation. I further added the debug points and found that coding is wating at: `public void initTransactions() {
        if (transactionManager == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot call initTransactions without setting a transactional id.");
        TransactionalRequestResult result = transactionManager.initializeTransactions();
        sender.wakeup();
        result.await();
    }
` of KafkaProducer class.

Comment: Have you tried the example in the javadoc? It's the second example from the top here http://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html . You will need a 0.11 Kafka broker as well and it has to be configured with 0.11 wire protocol

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that, i haven't tried the Javadoc example which you have pointed out, let me try that and revert here with my observations. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried which was mentioned above and still no luck. I reinstalled the kafka changed, jars but still no luck. Any pointers are much appreciated

Comment: What does DEBUG logging show for the javadoc example? Is it also stuck at initTransactions() with same error? Can you produce/consume successfully without transactions?

Comment: @HansJespersen I'm facing the same issue..Producer/Consumer is working fine without transactions but when I use transaction semantics `producer.beginTransactions()` call is blocking..

Comment: haven't got any solution yet.. still an open question without resolution.. please let me know if find any way

Comment: This is the example snippet from the intro blog https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nehanarkhede/6dd6f482c2091f36d2d55bd027ca6fc0/raw/071b173cea9ebbdf17e9ced10b167d48b5cb2f94/kafka-transactions.java

Comment: Are you maybe running against a single node cluster and it's blocked creating a topic with replication factor of 3?

Comment: try setting transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1 and transaction.state.log.min.isr=1 in your server.properties file if you are trying to do development on a single node cluster. Also verify that __transaction_state topic has been created with replication factor of 1.